# How to select a boot disk wie pxelinux

Tags: boot, pxe

I’ve configured a computer with pxelinux and I am able to boot from DHCP/TFTP. I can receive the bootloader and then boot from a local hdd or ssd. But I want to choose with the bootloader from which device it should boot. For example, on a computer with two devices, I want to choose from which device it should boot. I’ve fiddled around with the config from pxelinux and read the documentation, but it seems it only mentions the net boot process. Here is my example config file (default)

```
default ssd
prompt 1
ONTIMEOUT local
timeout 3000

MENU TITLE PXE Menu

LABEL hdd
    MENU LABEL Boot local hard drive
    root= (hd0,2)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.6-4-desktop
    initrd=(hd0,2)/boot/initrd-3.11.6-4-desktop

LABEL ssd
    MENU LABEL Boot local hard drive
    LOCALBOOT -1
```

It has pxelinux 6.0.3 and I’ve tried nearly every combination, but the only answer is always that it can’t find the kernel or `initrd` file, no matter if I say `/dev/sda2` or `(hd0,2)` or something.

Am I missing something, or is this task not possible with pxelinux?

---

For every option, the answer is always something is "No such file or directory", except for option "two", that boots ok. 
(I couldn't get a log from the console). tftp from client to server is working without any problems.

```
default menu.c32
prompt 0
ONTIMEOUT local
timeout 3000

MENU TITLE PXE Menu

LABEL one
        MENU LABEL Boot local hard drive
    root= hd0 2
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.6-4-desktop

LABEL two
        MENU LABEL Boot local hard drive
        LOCALBOOT 0

LABEL three
        MENU LABEL Boot local hard drive
    root=/dev/sda2
    kernel vmlinuz-3.11.6-4-desktop
    initrd=/boot/initrd-3.11.6-4-desktop.gz

LABEL four
        MENU LABEL VIER
    root=/dev/sda2 rw
        KERNEL ftp://179.99.99.1/chain.c32

LABEL five
    MENU LABEL Hole chain.c32 uebers Netz
    root hd0 2
    KERNEL chain.c32

LABEL six
        MENU LABEL VIER
    root=(hd0,2) rw
        KERNEL /boot/chain.c32

LABEL seven
    MENU LABEL Hole chain.c32 uebers Netz
    root hd0 2
    KERNEL /boot/chain.c32
    initrd=/boot/initrd-3.11.6-4-desktop.gz
```

---

The status of the xinetd daemon shows that the client tftp is requesting the files from the server. It seems, as if the client is getting the files from the server. But why does it not process it...

```
xinetd.service - Xinetd A Powerful Replacement For Inetd
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/xinetd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-06-29 16:08:46 CEST; 21min ago
 Main PID: 1536 (xinetd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xinetd.service
           |-1536 /usr/sbin/xinetd -stayalive -dontfork
           `-2938 in.tftpd -s /rde/installation/tftpboot -vvv

Jun 29 16:21:47 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[4161]: RRQ from ::ffff:199.99.99.10 filename menu.c32
Jun 29 16:22:32 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[4279]: RRQ from ::ffff:199.99.99.10 filename chain.c32
Jun 29 16:22:32 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[4280]: RRQ from ::ffff:199.99.99.10 filename chain.c32
Jun 29 16:22:36 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[4288]: RRQ from ::ffff:199.99.99.10 filename chain.c32
Jun 29 16:24:17 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[4544]: RRQ from ::ffff:199.99.99.10 filename pxelinux.0
Jun 29 16:24:17 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[4545]: RRQ from ::ffff:199.99.99.10 filename ldlinux.c32
Jun 29 16:24:17 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[4556]: RRQ from ::ffff:199.99.99.10 filename pxelinux.cfg/default
Jun 29 16:24:17 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[4558]: RRQ from ::ffff:199.99.99.10 filename menu.c32
Jun 29 16:24:34 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[4580]: RRQ from ::ffff:199.99.99.10 filename chain.c32
Jun 29 16:24:38 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[4588]: RRQ from ::ffff:199.99.99.10 filename chain.c32
```

Comment: @Mongrel: Please use more descriptive comments when you suggest edits.

Comment: in none of your options (one to seven) have you done what I suggested in my answer.  Get rid of the `root=` and just have a `KERNEL chain.c32` and `APPEND hd0 0` (to chainload the MBR of hd0.  alternatively `APPEND HD0 2` to chainload whatever boot-loader may be in partition 2, if any).   if `chain.c32` is not in the top-level tftp directory, then include the tftp path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out, how to configure pxelinux for my needs. tftp was already running and working, i made a "tail -f /var/log/messages" to discover that chain.c32 was not working (it was loading, but nothing happened):

```
2016-06-29T16:15 uaewg-srv xinetd[1536]: START: tftp from=::ffff:172.99.199.9
2016-06-29T16:15 uaewg-srv in.tftpd[2939]: RRQ from ::ffff:172.99.199.9 filename chain.c32
2016-06-29T16:18 uaewg-srv sshd[3183]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for uae_wg_sim from 127.0.0.1 port 54948 ssh2
```

Then i could try it with the other files, i provided the vmlinuz and initrd files in the **../tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default** config file:

```
prompt 0
ONTIMEOUT local
timeout 3000

MENU TITLE PXE Menu

LABEL local
        MENU LABEL Boot local hard drive
        LOCALBOOT 0

LABEL hdd
      kernel vmlinuz-3.11.6-4-desktop
      APPEND initrd=initrd-3.11.10-21-desktop  root=/dev/sda2
```

chain.c32, menu.c32 did either not worked on the system, i don´t know why, maybe i try to find out if i have time left, i am glad that it is now working.  **/var/log/messages** is a good help for error diagnostic, it was not clear, who was responsible for the tftpd, but i found out that it presumably was started by xinetd and not systemd. I changed the content of **/etc/xinetd.d/tftp** to :

```
service tftp
{
#   per_source      = 11
    cps         = 100 2
    socket_type     = dgram
    protocol        = udp
    wait            = yes
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args     = -s /rde/installation/tftpboot -vvv
    flags           = IPv6 IPv4
}
```

regards and thanks to cas for his help!

Comment: `chain.c32` didn't work because you weren't using it right. It needs arguments (the disk and partition to chainload), which are provided by the `APPEND` keyword....same as the vmlinuz kernel needs args (like an initrd filename and root filesystem device/label/uuid) which are provided by the APPEND keyword.  `LOCALBOOT` is probably better.

Comment: Hello cas, maybe i am too dull, but i can try what i want, i couldn´t get this chain.c32 running. I´ve configured as you advised (KERNEL /path/to/chain.c32
    APPEND hd0 2, where hd0,2 is /dev/sda2), and the chain.c32 is found on the server and served, /var/log/messages: 2016-07-01T08:00:23.  hostsrv in.tftpd[11275]: RRQ from ::ffff:172.21.143.10 filename chain.c32, but the hosts says"failed to load com32 file chain.c32". I suppose that there is something odd with my chain.c32 in conjunction with the loader, maybe it needs an update, but i can´t do this here. Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: have you installed a boot loader (like grub) in /dev/sda2?  almost certainly not - you've probably installed it into the MBR on /dev/sda.  so `APPEND hd0 0`, not `hd0 2`.

Comment: It doesn´t run with different disks either, maybe, there is something fundamental wrong but i can´t figure it out now because i can´t change the test system now. Maybe, if i set up a new system it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the chain loader ([chain.c32](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Chain.c32)) from [syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org/).  As with the other `syslinux` modules there are different versions for BIOS, efi32, and efi64.

```
LABEL local
    MENU DEFAULT
    MENU LABEL Boot from Local Hard Disk
    KERNEL /path/to/chain.c32
    APPEND hd0 2
```

That's adapted slightly from my `/srv/tftp/default` file - my version has `KERNEL http://ip.ip.ip.ip/tftp/chain.c32` (my httpd is configured to serve `/tftp/` from `/srv/tftp` - tftp would work just as well) and `APPEND hd0 0`.

Comment: Thanks, cas. But it seems, it is not working here. I tried only the path (/usr/share/syslinux/chain.c32) or path with device (hd0,2)/usr/share/syslinux/chain.c32, nothing works, all the time pxelinux is complaining that he can´t find the file. When i interrupt the bootprocess at the boot-command prompt (with e), and do a "ls  (hd0,2)/usr/share/syslinux/chain.c32" it finds that file. It is a mystery...

Comment: try serving chain.c32 via tftp or http.  that way you don't need to have it pre-installed on every machine.

Comment: since i do not install a web-service, i try to do it with tftp but until now, i could not find the description for pxelinux default config. I continue to do some research

Comment: While tftp is working and i can get the chain.c32 manual from remote with tftp, it is not working with pxelinux: LABEL vier
        MENU LABEL VIER
 root=(hd0,2)
        KERNEL tftp://172.21.143.1/chain.c32

Comment: try just `KERNEL chain.c32` (assuming `chain.c32` is in the top-level directory of your tftp server - e.g. `/srv/tftp/`.  BTW, it's probably best to just have `APPEND hd0` and rely on whatever boot-loader is in the MBR of the first disk.

Comment: Yes, i´ve tried all this, but it seems as if pxelinux does not know all these options. The only option, pxelinux can process is: LABEL xyz
        MENU LABEL Boot local hard drive
        LOCALBOOT 0

Comment: are you loading `menu.c32`?

Comment: no. Maybe i should ?

Comment: Still no success. Doesnt matter, if i add menu.c32 to the config file or arrange the options, no way, the client doesn´t find the files. That is unexplainable to me since the client obviously gets the default file at start, after the dhcp request, with tftp

Comment: please edit and add the updated version of your config file to your question (not in a comment).  also add the output of a complete netboot session from your tftp log (may need to be grepped out of /var/log/daemon.log or wherever).